# Apache server on Localhost stops working, logs show a segmentation fault, and connections get "Connection Reset" errors

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

After searching throught the internet for a while and trying all the fixes i've found(edit httpd.conf, vhost conf file, firewall) but still can't fix this error.

My server ran incredibly good yesterday and most parts of today, but at a certain time, it crashes and won't responds even after several restarts of the server and even the OS.

The server doesn't respond to only one script so it seems, and this is the script I need to run and debug.

The last time it crashed, PHP gave an error due to memory limit being reached, the error when I try to load the specific page: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`

EDIT:
While checking my error.log file I saw:

```
child pid 3549 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

Maybe this'll help you guys out

Hope you guys can help me out with this weird problem

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem! I've removed all my edits and now it's up and running again! Thanks so much :D!

Comment: You're welcome!  I've moved my comment into an answer so you can accept it as the solution, so your question is seen as "closed" and "resolved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segmentation faults usually indicate problems in the program that's running, either in the application that Apache is serving or in Apache itself.

What you need to do is check if your scripts or web applications are triggering such segmentation faults.  That's harder to trace.

If serving even plain static content causes the segmentation fault too, then you need to file a bug against Apache as it is misbehaving and may have a bug in it.

Answer (score -1):

On local #TYPO3 projects the generated temp files could be the reason. Clear all caches on typo3temp folder was the answer for me ;)

Comment: May you add more detail about what is the problem and how your suggestion can help? What is this `typo3temp` folder and how it is related to the problem? I don't see anywhere he mentioned that he is using typo3 on his server